# useState Causes a never ending call of a function

Tags: reactjs

Apologies relatively new to react

When i use the code below when the line `setDataVals(await MultipleDataSet(Multiple, CheckIds))` runs it creates a never ending loop of looking up this data and then updating the state

```
    const [arrCheckVals, setCheckVals] = useState('');
    const [arrDataVals, setDataVals] = useState([]);
    const [arrCheckDates, setArrCheckDates] = useState('');
    async function MultipleDataSet(CheckNames, IDs) {
        const promises = [];
        const OutOfLoopData = [];
        CheckNames.split(",").map(entry => {
            const InLoopData = []
            const result = axios.get('http://localhost:8080/check/chkmeas/vals/'+encodeURI(entry)+'/'+encodeURI(IDs))
            .then((response) => {
                //Set Response Data
                response.data.map((item,key)=> { 
                    InLoopData.push(item.Feild_Value)
                })
                promises.push(result);
                OutOfLoopData.push(InLoopData)
                return(InLoopData)
            })
            .catch('API Call 4 - Error: '+console.error);
        })
        const results = await Promise.all(promises)
        return(OutOfLoopData)
    }

        async function LoadData() {
                var CheckIds = await CheckLookupIDs() //Line ID's
                var CheckAPI = APIURL_3+FID+'/'+CheckIds //Lookup API Address
                setCheckVals(await CheckVals(CheckAPI)) //Lookup API Response
                setArrCheckDates(await CheckDates(CheckAPI))
                setDataVals(await MultipleDataSet(Multiple, CheckIds))
                return('')
        }
        LoadData()
```

I have tried removing other useState functions, I have rearranged the function, i have tried different methods in the function and i just can't prevent it from being in a never ending loop until it runs out of resources

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On every `setDataVals` (and other states), you'll trigger a new function calculation. However, in that function there's a `LoadData` call, which starts a new cycle.

Wrap the `LoadData` inside a `useEffect`:

```
useEffect(
    () => {
        LoadData();
    },
    []
);
```

That will trigger the cycle once only.

Comment: Brilliant thanks, great explanation too

Answer (score 1):

Everytime there's **any state update**, the function **LoadData would be called** according to your code.
We use React's useEffect hook for all such API calls or functions we need to call just once.

useEffect with **empty** dependency array would trigger just once.

So, you can go with

```
useEffect(() => {
  // API calls
  LoadData();
}, []);
```

Otherwise, it'd always go in an infinite loop if you directly call the function.